# necessary data rewind wasn't possible with WEBDAV

Tags: laravel, webdav, sabredav

I using [Laravel WebDAV wrapper](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-webdav) which uses [Sabre](https://github.com/sabre-io/dav) to upload media to the WebDAV server that uses the basic authentication using Nginx but according to the default package set in the documentation I used this configuration in `filesystem.php`:

```
    'dav' => [
        'driver' => 'webdav',
        'baseUri' => 'https://dav.example.com/',
        'userName' => 'test',
        'password' => 'test',
    ],
```

But I get this error when trying to store a file with the Laravel Storage:

> necessary data rewind wasn't possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the authentication is needed for connection to the server the `authType` setting must be set. for me, it should be `1` for basic authentication.

```
    'dav' => [
        'driver' => 'webdav',
        'baseUri' => 'https://dav.example.com/',
        'userName' => 'test',
        'password' => 'test',
        'authType' => 1,
    ],
```